# Android Google Map Marker not repositioning correctly

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, google-play-services, google-maps-markers

I am displaying a Google map in an Android application with two markers. On the **onMapReady** method everything works well, the map renders and the markers appear with the relevant bitmaps and information.

I have even implemented a zoom boundary using the **CameraUpdateFactory()** function with **LatLngBounds**. Again, up to this point, **everything works well and as expected**. Here's the snippet:

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {
  myGoogleMap = googleMap   

  // myMapMarker is a global variable of type MarkerOptions
  // the options are set only once here and never changed elsewhere in the code
  myMapMarker = MarkerOptions()
                .position(LatLng(34.1478, 118.1445))
                .title("My Location")
                .snippet("Description of my location...")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(pinBitmap))

  // myMapMarker is added to the map only once here and
  // never removed or added again elsewhere in the code
  myGoogleMap?.addMarker(myMapMarker)
}
```

However, when I try to reposition the marker using the marker **setPosition** function *(just **position** in Kotlin)*, the marker position is changed but the pin remains in its original position, with the info-window still functional. I know that the marker position is updated because the next call to the *zoom to bounds* function zooms in to the new boundaries.

```
// only one attempt is made to move myMapMarker here 
// the marker location is successfully changed 
// >>> evidenced by println(myMapMarker?.location)
// the marker icon/pin is not re-positioned
myMapMarker?.position(LatLng(mapData.latitude, mapData.longitude))
```

I've read that the markers should be **re-positioned** and not removed & added again. So, is there a missing step in getting the marker to reposition correctly?

I've also tried to downgrade the Google Play Maps API from 17 to 16, but still getting the same results.

TIA.

---

**EDIT: Adding a screenshot to illustrate the issue**

[image]

The original marker was at 452 Ford Place *(the red marker).* After performing a **setPosition()**, the red marker should appear where the blue marker is, but it doesn't. It stays at 452 Ford Place.

Comment: what did you mean by pin?

Comment: The icon representing the marker that can be tapped to display the info window.

Comment: Can you provide any screen shot of the problem

Comment: @AbuYousuf I've expanded my answer with the screenshot. Any direction would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think your are reinitialize `myMapMarker` so that the previous marker stays same

Comment: @AbuYousuf The variable `myMapMarker` is a global variable defined as **MarkerOptions**. `myMapMarker` is initialized only once in the **onMapReady()** method. Then later, when the location is updated, `myMapMarker` is moved with the **setPosition()** function. No reinitialization - only the position is changed. But the display is not updated to show the icon in the new position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was staring me in the face the whole time.

I have been adding **MarkerOptions** to the map instead of **Marker**. That is why the position data *(marker options)* changed but not the marker position itself.

Problem solved!

Added extra code for clarity

```kotlin
// adding a marker to the map object returns a reference to the marker
val marker = map.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
                .position(LatLng(34.1478, 118.1445))
                .title("My Location")
                .snippet("Description of my location...")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(pinBitmap)))

// which can be used to update its position
marker.position = LatLng(newLocation.latitude, newLocation.longitude)
```

Comment: can you please explain?